# MS Access 2019 (64 bit) on windows 10 (64 bit) crashes when calling the GDIP GetImageGraphicsContext or GdipCreateHBITMAPFromBitmap function

Tags: vba, ms-access, graphics, 64-bit, gdi+

### MS Access 2019 (64 bit) on windows 10 (64 bit) crashes when calling the GDIP GetImageGraphicsContext or GdipCreateHBITMAPFromBitmap function

```
    Declaration part______________________
GDIP code from:
'-------------------------------------------------
'    Picture functions using GDIPlus-API (GDIP)   |
'-------------------------------------------------
'    *  Office 2003/2007/2010 version  *          |
'-------------------------------------------------
'   (c) mossSOFT / Sascha Trowitzsch rev. 04/2010 |
'-------------------------------------------------
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
...Private Enum PixelFormat
    PixelFormat1bppIndexed = &H30101
    PixelFormat4bppIndexed = &H30402
    pixelFormat8bppIndexed = &H30803
    PixelFormat16bppGreyScale = &H101004
    PixelFormat16bppRGB555 = &H21005
    PixelFormat16bppRGB565 = &H21006
    PixelFormat16bppARGB1555 = &H61007
    PixelFormat24bppRGB = &H21808
    PixelFormat32bppRGB = &H22009
    PixelFormat32bppARGB = &H26200A
    PixelFormat32bppPARGB = &HE200B
    PixelFormat48bppRGB = &H10300C
    PixelFormat64bppARGB = &H34400D
    PixelFormat64bppPARGB = &H1C400E
    PixelFormatMax = 15 '&HF
End Enum
...

Dim lGraph As Long
Dim lBitmap2 As Long
Dim lBitmap As Long
...
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GdipCreateBitmapFromScan0 Lib "gdiplus" (ByVal Width As Long, ByVal Height As Long, ByVal stride As Long, ByVal PixelFormat As Long, scan0 As Any, bitmap As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GdipGetImageGraphicsContext Lib "gdiplus" (ByVal Image As Long, graphics As Long) As Long
...

Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim locRet as Long

InitGDIP '-> appaears to work fine

locRet = GdipCreateBitmapFromScan0(CLng(600), CLng(600), 0&, PixelFormat32bppARGB, ByVal 0&, lBitmap2) ' <- Appears to work fine until here (return value = 0)
locRet = GdipGetImageGraphicsContext(lBitmap2, lGraph)   <- MS ACCESS 2019 crashes
```

or

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
locRet = GdipCreateHBITMAPFromBitmap(lBitmap2, hBitmap, CLng(BackGrndClr)) ' <- MS ACCESS 2019 crashes here
```

...

I tried to use different data types for the 'lGraph' variable, but there is a pre-compiler error when changing the data type because of a data type incomatibility so this did not help. 
Does someone know how to make it work again? Under Windows 7 (64 bit, I guess) and MS Access 2016 32 bit, it works fine, wtihout any issue -> I try to move now to W10 64 bit and Access 2019 (64 bit).

Access crashes also when calling the GdipCreateHBITMAPFromBitmap function…

There appears to be a systematic issue...

Answer (score 1):

If you want your API calls to be 64-bit compatible, you need to use `LongPtr` wherever you're passing a pointer.

Slapping `PtrSafe` on your function is not actually going to make the pointers safe, you need to do that yourself, and that keyword is there to indicate you have done that, and the function is safe for use in 64-bit. If you use that without verifying that you've changed all the pointers from `Long` to `LongPtr`, VBA will hard-crash when calling the function in a 64-bit application (and in rare cases you can even destabilize other applications).

As far as I can see, `Graph` and `bitmap` are the only pointers used in those functions, so you need to use a `LongPtr` when storing and passing those, but my GDI knowledge is a bit limited.

```
Dim lGraph As LongPtr
Dim lBitmap2 As LongPtr
Dim lBitmap As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GdipCreateBitmapFromScan0 Lib "gdiplus" (ByVal Width As Long, ByVal Height As Long, ByVal stride As Long, ByVal PixelFormat As Long, scan0 As Any, bitmap As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GdipGetImageGraphicsContext Lib "gdiplus" (ByVal Image As LongPtr, graphics As LongPtr) As Long
```

Comment: I changed the declaration to:

Comment: Hi Erik

Many thanks, I changed the declaration to

Dim lGraph As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GdipGetImageGraphicsContext Lib "gdiplus" (ByVal Image As LongPtr, graphics As LongPtr) As Long

--> I get an compilation error at 

locRet = GdipGetImageGraphicsContext(lBitmap2, lGraph)

the compiler mentioned that the lGraph argument is incompatible byRef ?
Best regards
Daniel

Comment: Oh, that might be correct. If that's the case, you just need to use `ByVal`, and pass `VarPtr(graphics)` instead of `graphics`.

Comment: Hm.. I tried with ByVal and VarPtr, changed the type of the graphics variable to Object, StdPicture, aso ... -> no way.. :-(

Comment: Huh? Changed it to Object? That's not right, it should stay as-is. `ByVal VarPtr(Something)` is equal to `ByRef Something` in external API calls, no further changes needed.

Comment: Dim lGraph As LongPtr  
Dim lBitmap2 As Long  
  
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GdipCreateBitmapFromScan0 Lib "gdiplus" (ByVal Width As Long, ByVal Height As Long, ByVal stride As Long, ByVal PixelFormat As Long, scan0 As Any, bitmap As Long) As Long  
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GdipGetImageGraphicsContext Lib "gdiplus" (ByVal Image As Long, graphics As LongPtr) As Long  
  
locRet = GdipCreateBitmapFromScan0(CLng(600), CLng(600), 0&, PixelFormat32bppARGB, ByVal 0&, lBitmap2)  '<- still ok  
locRet = GdipGetImageGraphicsContext(lBitmap2, ByVal VarPtr(lGraph))  '<- still nok

Comment: Wut? You haven't implemented most of the changes I suggested! `Bitmap` is still long, image too, those should be `LongPtr`

Comment: ooops, sorry. Is now LongPtr -> no crash -> great   locRet = 2, I will have to check and to adjust all the other functions around, will let you know again, might take a while...

Comment: A part of my program works again, many many thanks for your help, great. I still strugle with the FillPolygon function it Returns a value of 2 -> invalid paramter…

Comment: Private Enum GpStatus ' aka Status
    Ok = 0
    GenericError = 1
    InvalidParameter = 2
    OutOfMemory = 3
...
End Enum

Private Type POINTF
    x As Single
    y As Single
End Type

Dim Polygon(4) As POINTF

'32 Bit:  GdipFillPolygon Lib "gdiplus" (ByVal graphics As Long, ByVal Brush As Long, Points As POINTF, ByVal count As Long, ByVal FillMd As FillMode) As GpStatus
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GdipFillPolygon Lib "gdiplus" (ByVal graphics As LongPtr, ByVal Brush As Long, ByVal Points As LongPtr, ByVal count As Long, ByVal FillMd As FillMode) As GpStatus

Comment: locRet = GdipFillPolygon(ByVal VarPtr(LocMapGraph), LocBrush, ByVal VarPtr(Polygon(0)), CLng(4), FillModeWinding)   ------> Result: 2 (invalid Parameter...)

Comment: Declaration: Points As POINTF   and passing the Polygon paramter as Polygon(0) (as in the 32 Bit original) ended also with the result: 2 ...